# How to autofill a field from a variable in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form for entering information, each user must "login" by entering their name when they start up my database. I would like to auto populate each records "User" field with this name they have logged in with.

I already have the whole login setup except I cant for the life of me work out how to insert the UserName string contents into a field when the user hits save.

Comment: Do you not wish to use the windows log-in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not wish to use Windows log-in details, the safest and easiest thing is a table. I generally keep a one row table to hold various details and current user name would work well in such a table. It can be deleted from the table in the log-in script and then updated when the user logs in. You can use DLookUp throughout your application to get the user name.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend saving the login Username to a global variable.  Then in your save method, grab that global variable username and insert it into the field.  Look up using global variables and you'll see its pretty easy to use.

Comment: Global variables are volatile and are reset on unhandled errors.

Comment: Yes, but for a simple database application, they are fast and easy to use and I never ran into an issue with the variables being reset in several years of use.